# Can I use "if lt IE9" in conjunction with "if IE 8"?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Can I use `if lt IE9` in conjunction with `if IE 8`, in this manner:

```html
<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie8"> <![endif]-->
```

I'm asking since the second condition is contained in the first one, maybe this could cause some glitch in one of the browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it should work fine, and the order doesn't matter, ie will parse all the rules and execute any that matches

Comment: Sorry, the order doesn't matter, it was my mistake, thought i remembered a problem, but just tested it, and order doesn't matter